# Neo4J Android Support for Graph DB

Tags: neo4j

Is Neo4J Team not maintaining android library to provide support for Graph DB? 
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android

Last commit was made 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read and understand, the answer is: no, they are not.

I'm not sure if you realize this or not, but the repository you have posted a link to is maintained under a community-contributed account. If you look at the account description on the account page (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib), you'll see the following:

> Public, Open Source Contributions to the Neo4j Ecosystem: Tools, Drivers, Documentation, Visualization

Therefore - this project is only maintained by the contributions and efforts of the Neo4j community rather than the Neo4j team itself.

Not sure if it fits your use case, but if you're building Android apps, the Neo4j team does provide officially supported Java drivers that would allow you to connect to a remote Neo4j database, see the following for information on that:

https://neo4j.com/developer/java/